# Use of Regex in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

```
create table numbers (number varchar(10));
insert into numbers (number) values
('9999999999'),
('5532003644'), 
('1212121205'),                                      
('1103220311'),                                     
('1121212128'),
('1234123425');
```

Trying to SELECT only XY-XY-XY series from the database:

```
SELECT * FROM numbers
where number regexp '(.*([0-9])\2.*){3}'
```

Giving me results:

> 1212121205, 1121212128 & 1234123425

---

How ***1234123425*** is XY-XY-XY series?

#### [DB-FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2sdEBRtJw8jV9ap7be6FYD/0)

Comment: What I find strange is that your query is returning all the results that *don't* match the regex... https://regex101.com/r/dQrJR7/1

Comment: Are these your expected results? https://regex101.com/r/rMW7i1/1

Comment: I don't understand this at all. How does `([0-9])\2` match XY? Shouldn't it match XX?

Comment: @Thefourthbird my expected results are only: **1212121205 & 1121212128**

Comment: @Barmar so what will be the regex that matches XY?

Comment: Then you want `(..).*\1.*\1`, but what about `9999999999`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol `9999999999` is **XX** not ***XY***

Comment: @paran so you want a solution only with regex?

Comment: You need to double the backslash. `\2` is just matching the digit 2, it's not a back-reference.

Comment: [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4cXEvuGV2m8CtWJe9XNw1R/1) is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: @CodeManiac Yes, exactly the same!

Comment: @forpas not neccessary

Comment: MySQL might just not support `\2`. So `\2` and `\\2` are the same as just `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your questions are interesting sql puzzles.
This solution also, does not involve regex:

```
select distinct n.number
from (
  select 1 start union all select 2  union all select 3 union all 
  select 4 union all select 5 
) s cross join numbers n
where 
  left(substring(n.number, s.start, 2), 1) <> right(substring(n.number, s.start, 2), 1)
  and
  n.number like concat(
    '%', substring(n.number, s.start, 2), 
    substring(n.number, s.start, 2),
    '%', substring(n.number, s.start, 2), '%'
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2sdEBRtJw8jV9ap7be6FYD/13).
Results:

```
| number     |
| ---------- |
| 1212121205 |
| 1121212128 |
```

Comment: If I want XYZ-XYZ, I [tried this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2sdEBRtJw8jV9ap7be6FYD/3). Is that a correct way?

Comment: No, because I assume that you want all 3 chars of XYZ to be different or at least not all the same(?). This is more complicated.

Comment: Yes all different!

Comment: Instead of `left(substring(n.number, s.start, 2), 1) <> right(substring(n.number, s.start, 3), 1)` which compares the 1st and the last char of XY you must do 3 comparisons for XYZ, the 1st with the 2nd, the 1st with the 3d, and the 2nd with the 3d must all be different.

Comment: I think I am very near to the results: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2sdEBRtJw8jV9ap7be6FYD/4

Comment: Give me a few mins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196099/discussion-between-paran-and-forpas).

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that you're not escaping the backslash. Backslash is both a string escape and a regexp escape; to get it into the regexp engine, you need to escape it for the string parser. Otherwise, `\2` is treated as simply `2`, so `([0-9])\2` matches any digit follwed by `2`.

But you don't need to use a back-reference. `\2` will match whatever `([0-9])` matched, which will make your code look for XX, not XY. I don't think there's a way to write a regexp where you match any character *other* than the back-reference.

Comment: I think, [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4cXEvuGV2m8CtWJe9XNw1R/1) will give me my expected results. Is there any issue in that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite an answer, but you can do this with regular expressions.  The problem is that MySQL does not support back references.  Postgres, does, so the following does what you intend:

```
SELECT *
FROM numbers
WHERE number ~ '([0-9]{2}).*(\1).*(\1)'
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v5vFv1iTVs9SzBPYEeqWGa/0) is a dbfiddle.